# How to prevent flooding of messages to socket.io server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, chat

I wrote chat application using NodeJs and Socket.io. It works fine but at the moment there is nothing stopping malicious user from flooding server with large number of messages. What would be the best way to avoid this kind of situation?

BTW I did quite a bit of research and currently it seems that the only option would be simply tracking frequency of messages that user sends to server and if its over certain threshold disconnect socket or simply ignore messages. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'd also love to find an answer to this! Seems like such an obvious issue that I'd imagine there would be many answers to. But I too can't seem to find many answers.

Comment: Glad I'm not alone :) I end up testing if the interval between consecutive messages is shorter then X miliseconds and if this is repeated 10 times or so then disconnects. so short interval between lets say 5 messages is ok but if this happens 10 times disconnect.